# Sorting objects and lists in nested JSON

Tags: python, json, sorting, nested

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Contact": {
        "Name": "Name_of_the_shop"
      },
      "Date": "2022-01-01T11:11:13",
      "DueDate": "2022-01-01T11:11:13",
      "VAT": false,
      "Items": [
        {
          "Code": "3",
          "Description": "Sales",
          "Quantity": 1,
          "TaxAmount": 1,
          "TaxType": "3",
          "UnitAmount": 10
        },
        {
          "AccountCode": "1",
          "Description": "Discount",
          "Quantity": 1,
          "TaxAmount": -0.2,
          "TaxType": "4",
          "UnitAmount": -2
        },
        {
          "AccountCode": "1",
          "Description": "Discount",
          "Quantity": 3,
          "TaxAmount": 1.9,
          "TaxType": "4",
          "UnitAmount": -5
        },
        {
          "Code": "3",
          "Description": "Sales",
          "Quantity": 2,
          "TaxAmount": 1,
          "TaxType": "3",
          "UnitAmount": 8
        }
      ],
      "Payments": [],
      "Reference": "Orders closed 1 Febuary 2022"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this code to extract all keys and values:

```
def get_keys_and_values(data, key_list, value_list):
    for key, value in data.items():
        key_list.append(key)
        if not isinstance(value, list) and not isinstance(value, dict):
            value_list.append([key, value])
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            get_keys_and_values(value, key_list, value_list)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for val in value:
                get_keys_and_values(val, key_list, value_list)
    return key_list, value_list
```

I want to sort all dictionaries and lists in this JSON so the output (key_list and value_list) is always the same even if order in the JSON will change. (I dont want to sort key_list, and value_list it has to be done here). I'm relatively new to Python, and I've been stuck here for a while, I would appreciate any help :)

Expected outpu:

key_list:

```
['AccountCode', 'AccountCode', 'Code', 'Code', 'Contact', 'Date', 'Description', 'Description', 'Description', 'Description', 'DueDate', 'Items', 'Name', 'Payments', 'Quantity', 'Quantity', 'Quantity', 'Quantity', 'Reference', 'TaxAmount', 'TaxAmount', 'TaxAmount', 'TaxAmount', 'TaxType', 'TaxType', 'TaxType', 'TaxType', 'UnitAmount', 'UnitAmount', 'UnitAmount', 'UnitAmount', 'VAT', 'data']
```

value_list:

```
[
['Date', '2022-01-01T11:11:13'],
['DueDate', '2022-01-01T11:11:13'],
['Name', 'Name_of_the_shop'],
['Reference', 'Orders closed 1 Febuary 2022']
['VAT', False],
[['AccountCode', '1'], ['Description', 'Discount'], ['TaxAmount', -0.2], ['TaxType', '4'], ['Quantity', 1], ['UnitAmount', -2]],
[['AccountCode', '1'], ['Description', 'Discount'], ['TaxAmount', 1.9], ['TaxType', '4'], ['Quantity', 3], ['UnitAmount', -5]],
[['Code', '3'], ['Description', 'Sales'], ['TaxAmount', 1], ['TaxType', '3'], ['Quantity', 1], ['UnitAmount', 10]],
[['Code', '3'], ['Description', 'Sales'], ['TaxAmount', 1], ['TaxType', '3'], ['Quantity', 2], ['UnitAmount', 8]]
]
```

Comment: Please post the output you want.

Comment: @timgeb I've added expeted output in the post

Comment: Any consistent ordering would work for me

Answer (score 2):

Try using the json library with the sort_keys feature.

```
import json

sorted_json_data = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)
```